# Is it possible to get reference to ListView from Adapter in Android?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Is it possible to get reference to ListView from Adapter in Android without passing it as an argument to constructor?

Comment: No, but reverse is possible.

Comment: You're supposed to do it the other way... Adapter should not know about the UI component which it is being used. It is simply a provider, and does not care about who is receiving the data. Although the ListView knows and cares about which adapter is feeding the data, and provides a way to change it if necessary. I'm sorry to say, but something is up-side-down in your architecture...

Comment: @Madushan thanks for answer. I use ExpandableListView, and I need to collapse all the groups when expand another. So I override onExpandGroup in adapter. So I need reference to listview

Comment: I assume you have an implementation of `ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener` . Can you pass the reference to the list view to its constructor ?. (I assume you set it using `setOnGroupExpandListener` at the constructor of your activity, which 'knows' the List View)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is definitely possible. Should it be done or not (Yes there are cases).

```
// See this method of your adapter
// The parent is the view you are looking for
public override View GetGroupView(int groupPosition, bool isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ListView view = (ListView)parent;
}
```

Comment: Right, working :) although i'm dealing with `expandableListView` but got the idea from you +1.

Comment: Wonderful! So simple.

Comment: That's fine, but is it a good practice or should it be avoided?

Comment: It is a harmful method. Practice depends on who is using this and how

Comment: I meant harmless. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<IItemListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<ProductModel> designerCollection;
    ArrayList<ProductModel> designerCollectionforreward;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListItemClickListener listItemClickListener;
    boolean isProducthide;
    boolean isEditable;
    ProductModel myListDataforReward;


    public ItemListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ProductModel> designerCollection, ArrayList<ProductModel> designerCollectionforreward, boolean isProducthide, boolean isEditable, ListItemClickListener listItemClickListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.designerCollection = designerCollection;
        this.designerCollectionforreward = designerCollectionforreward;
        this.listItemClickListener = listItemClickListener;
        this.isProducthide = isProducthide;
        this.isEditable = isEditable;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_layout_cart_product, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(listItem);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final ProductModel myListData = designerCollection.get(position);
        if (designerCollectionforreward != null) {
            myListDataforReward = designerCollectionforreward.get(position);
        }
        Glide.with(holder.itemView)
                .load(myListData.getProductImage())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.noimage)
                .into(holder.iv_product_image);
        if (isProducthide) {
            holder.iv_product_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.iv_product_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        holder.tv_product_price.setText(myListData.getProductPrice());
        holder.imgDelete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        holder.imgDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                listItemClickListener.onItemClick(position, myListData.getItemQuantity(), myListData.getShoppingId());
            }
        });

        holder.tv_product_name.setText(myListData.getProductName());
        holder.txt_quantity.setText(myListData.getItemQuantity());
        holder.tv_product_qty.setText(myListData.getItemQuantity());

        if (myListData.isRemoveDisable()) {
            holder.imgDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.imgDelete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

//        holder.tv_require.setText(myListData.getRequireText());
        if (myListDataforReward != null) {
            if (myListDataforReward.getProductRewardPoint() != null && !myListDataforReward.getProductRewardPoint().isEmpty()) {
                holder.ll_product_reward_point.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (Constants.hashMap.containsKey("rewardpoint.plugin.rewardpoints.willearn")) {
                    holder.tv_reward_title.setText(Constants.hashMap.get("rewardpoint.plugin.rewardpoints.willearn"));
                } else {
                    holder.tv_reward_title.setText("You will earn : ");
                }
                holder.tv_reward_point.setText(myListDataforReward.getProductRewardPoint() + " "
                        + Constants.hashMap.get("admin.customers.customers.rewardpoints.fields.points"));
            } else {
                holder.ll_product_reward_point.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } else {
            holder.ll_product_reward_point.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if (myListData.getAttributeString() != null && !myListData.getAttributeString().equals("")) {
            holder.btnEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.txtAttribute.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.txtAttribute.setText(myListData.getAttributeString());
        } else {
            holder.txtAttribute.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.btnEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        /*if (myListData.getAttributeString().equals("")) {
            holder.ll_editProduct.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.btnEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }*/
        /*if (isEditable) {
            holder.ll_editProduct.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.btnEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.btnEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }*/

        holder.tv_main_price.setText(myListData.getItemsubtotal());
        int qty = Integer.parseInt(designerCollection.get(position).getItemQuantity());
        int maxQty = designerCollection.get(position).getOrder_maximum_quantity();

            holder.plus_quantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
//                    if (qty < maxQty) {
                    int qty = Integer.parseInt(designerCollection.get(position).getItemQuantity());
                    holder.txt_quantity.setText(String.valueOf(qty + 1));
                    designerCollection.get(position).setItemQuantity(String.valueOf(qty + 1));
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    listItemClickListener.onItemClick(position, String.valueOf(1), "quantity");

//                    } else {
//                        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    }
                }
            });
        holder.minus_quantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int qty = Integer.parseInt(designerCollection.get(position).getItemQuantity());
                if (qty > 1) {
                    if (qty == Integer.parseInt(designerCollection.get(position).getOrder_minimum_quantity())) {
                        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "minimum quantity must be " + Integer.parseInt(designerCollection.get(position).getOrder_minimum_quantity()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        holder.txt_quantity.setText(String.valueOf(qty - 1));
                        designerCollection.get(position).setItemQuantity(String.valueOf(qty - 1));
                        listItemClickListener.onItemClick(position, String.valueOf(-1), "quantity");
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        holder.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ProductDetailActivity.class)
                        .putExtra(Constants.INTENT_PRODUCT_ID, myListData.getProductId())
                        .putExtra(Constants.productAttribute, (Serializable) myListData.getProductAttributeValueModelList())
                        .putExtra(Constants.isFromCartScreen, true));
                ((Activity) context).finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return designerCollection.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final TextView plus_quantity, minus_quantity;
        CardView cart;
        public ImageView iv_product_image, img_dropDown;
        TextView tv_product_name, tv_product_price, txt_quantity, tv_product_qty, txtAttribute, tv_main_price;
        CustomSpinner ll_spinner;
        LinearLayout ll_click, ll_editProduct, ll_product_reward_point;
        CircleImageView imgDelete;

        TextView txtPrice, txtQuant, txtTotal, tv_reward_title, tv_reward_point;
        CircleImageView btnEdit;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.setIsRecyclable(false);
            iv_product_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_product_image);
            tv_product_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_name);
            ll_product_reward_point = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_product_reward_point);
//            tv_product_names = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_names);
            imgDelete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgDelete);
//            cart = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart);

            btnEdit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
//            product_tags = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_tags);

            tv_reward_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_reward_title);
            tv_reward_point = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_reward_point);
//            tv_require = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_require);
            txtPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
            txtQuant = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtQty);
            txtTotal = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTotal);

            plus_quantity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.plus_quantity);
            minus_quantity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.minus_quantity);
//            text_quantity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_quantity);
            tv_product_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_name);
            tv_product_price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_price);
            txt_quantity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_quantity);
            tv_product_qty = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_qty);
            txtAttribute = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAttributeName);
            tv_main_price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_main_price);
            ll_click = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_click);
            ll_editProduct = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_editProduct);
            if (Constants.hashMap.containsKey("admin.catalog.products.fields.price"))
                txtPrice.setText(Constants.hashMap.get("admin.catalog.products.fields.price"));
            if (Constants.hashMap.containsKey("shoppingcart.quantity"))
                txtQuant.setText(Constants.hashMap.get("shoppingcart.quantity"));
            if (Constants.hashMap.containsKey("admin.currentcarts.total"))
                txtTotal.setText(Constants.hashMap.get("admin.currentcarts.total"));
        }
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        designerCollection.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public void restoreItem(ProductModel item, int position) {
        designerCollection.add(position, item);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public ArrayList<ProductModel> getData() {
        return designerCollection;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

No it is not possible, layout should be known to adapter.